# python Help with calculating the average and std on excel files

Tags: python, xlrd

im trying to calculate the average and std for x, y, and z column for about 50 excel files that i saved in a folder. each excel files has x values in the first column, y in the second, and z in the third column. im using this script, but it kept giving me error. All the files are saved as ".xls". please help and if you guys know any other way i can do this that would be very helpful. Here is the Script and the error:

```
    import xlrd
    import numpy
    import os

    path = "E:\\hello\\Patient"
    dirList=os.listdir(path)
    f = open('E:\\hello\\try.xls', 'w')
    f.write('Patient_ID, Xavg, xstd, yavg, ystd, zavg, ystd')
    f.write("\n")

    ##print dirList
    ##i = 0
    Col_values=[]
    for file in dirList:
        fullpath = os.path.join(path,file)
    ##    print fullpath
        if os.path.isfile(fullpath) == 1:
            wb = xlrd.open_workbook(fullpath)
            sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
            f.write(str(file))
            f.write(", ")
            for i in range(0,3):
                for j in range(sh.nrows):
                    Col_values.append(sh.cell(j,i).value)
                a = numpy.average(Col_values)
                b = numpy.std(Col_values)
                f.write(str(a))
                f.write(", ")
                f.write(str(b))
                f.write(", ")
            f.write("\n")

    f.close()
```

Comment: All of the files are saved as " Microsoft office excel 97-2003 worksheet". so im guessing that means the files are saved as "xls" files.

Comment: You can check by trying to open one of the files in a text editor.  If it's an Excel file you should see a lot of garbage.  It's worth checking because you get the same error if you try to open a text file with xlrd.

Comment: i checked...i believe its an excel file.

Comment: But how did you check it?  Did you open it in a text editor (like Notepad in Windows, or vi or emacs in Linux/Unix)?

Answer (score 0):

Do it step by step to verify that you are able to read something from the xls-files.  Use the hardcoded absolute path to the file. BTW, code looks ok (as far as I can tell) Error is probably in the xls-file...

Something like:

```
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('myworkbook.xls')

#Get the first sheet either by index or by name

sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
sh = wb.sheet_by_name(u'Sheet1')

#Index individual cells:

cell_A1 = sh.cell(0,0).value
```

Comment: did that on one of the excel file and i was able to read the values.

Comment: @Temesgen-Abba ok, does the path `E:\\hello\\Patient` contain something else than .xls-files? You code loops over *all* files in that folder...

Comment: no all of the files in the folder are excel files saved as xls.

Comment: then print the value of `fullpath` for each iteration (add a ` sys.stdout.flush()` to see what file is causing the exception; then check that one using the steps above...

Comment: when i print the fullpath...it only prints the fullpath for the first file only and it prints out the error. i have more than 50 files in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Besides reading Excel files, your script is trying to write one as well.  It's not going to work.  You need to use the xlwt package to write .xls files.  Your approach to writing right now looks more like CSV.  If all your so-called Excel files are really CSV files (despite the *name* ending in .xls), then xlrd is not going to read them properly.

If you really want to work with Excel files, you should use both xlrd (to read) and xlwt (to write).  If you can get by working with CSV files, you shouldn't be using xlrd at all.  You should be using Python's included csv module instead (for both reading and writing .csv files).

Comment: I promise you, any file you generate with your script is NOT an Excel file.  Just because it can be opened with Excel doesn't automatically make it an Excel file.  The file you write with this script is a CSV that happens to have a name ending in .xls.  As for your read error, the message you have indicated strongly suggests that xlrd encountered a CSV file instead of an Excel file.

Comment: how can i make sure that its an Excel file that can be read with xlrd?

Comment: Accually i figured it out. now i know what the problem is. Thank you tho.